# Помогите с Telegram BOT сделать цикл на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, while

Есть часть кода для бота Telegram. **Бот задает вопрос: Введите страницу.** (При этом всего страниц 40)
Помогите написать правильно **цикл для проверки сообщения от пользователя**, который отвечает боту на этот вопрос. Надо чтобы бот ждал от пользователя пока он введёт число от 1 до 40, если он вводит неправильно, то бот сообщает ему об этом и снова ждёт, когда человек введёт правильно страницу. **N - глобальная переменная, обозначающая номер страницы.**

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def get_Info(message):
        global N;
        while N == 0:
            #проверяем что номер страницы изменился
            try:
                N = int(message.text) #проверяем, что номер страницы введен корректно
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='✅Замечательно! Вы выбрали страницу: '+str(N)+' ');
            except Exception:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Цифрами, пожалуйста')
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def request_page(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите страницу')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, verify_page)


def verify_page(message):
    if int(message.text.isdigit()):  # проверяем что введённое сообщение от пользователя является цифрой
        if int(message.text) in range(1, 41):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали страницу {}'.format(message.text))
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите верный номер страницы')
            request_page(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Номер страницы должен быть числом')
        request_page(message)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает!

Comment: если ответ помог Вам, пожалуйста отметьте его как решение, это поможет другим участникам. так же Вы можете проголосовать За.